# How to trace http.Client with httptrace in Go

Tags: http, go, google-api, androidpublisher

Per this [doc](https://go.dev/blog/http-tracing), we can trace `http.Client` with `httptrace` in this way

```golang
    t := &transport{}

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://google.com", nil)
    trace := &httptrace.ClientTrace{
        GotConn: t.GotConn,
    }
    req = req.WithContext(httptrace.WithClientTrace(req.Context(), trace))

    client := &http.Client{Transport: t}
```

For [google API client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/master/androidpublisher/v3/androidpublisher-gen.go#L87), here are the one wrapper codes

```golang
func NewWithClient(jsonKey []byte, cli *http.Client) (*Client, error) {
    if cli == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("client is nil")
    }

    ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), oauth2.HTTPClient, cli)

    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(jsonKey, androidpublisher.AndroidpublisherScope)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    service, err := androidpublisher.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(conf.Client(ctx)))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &Client{service}, err
}
```

We want to apply `httptrace` to the `http.Client` argument of `NewWithClient` to do HTTP trace.

What we have tried

```golang
type TraceTransport struct {
}

var traceTransport = &TraceTransport{}

var trace = &httptrace.ClientTrace{
    GotConn: traceTransport.GotConn,
}

func (t *TraceTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
}

func (t *TraceTransport) GotConn(info httptrace.GotConnInfo) {
    fmt.Printf("Connection reused for %v \n", info.Reused)
}

type ClientWrapper struct {
    defaultClient *http.Client
}

var clientWrapperTrace = &httptrace.ClientTrace{GotConn: traceTransport.GotConn}

func (c *ClientWrapper) Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    req = req.WithContext(httptrace.WithClientTrace(req.Context(), clientWrapperTrace))
    return c.defaultClient.Do(req)
}

func NewClientTrace(jsonKey []byte) (*Client, error) {
    cli := &http.Client{
        Transport: traceTransport,
        Timeout:   time.Duration(10) * time.Second,
    }
    cliWrapper := &ClientWrapper{defaultClient: cli}
    ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), oauth2.HTTPClient, cliWrapper)

    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(jsonKey, androidpublisher.AndroidpublisherScope)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    service, err := androidpublisher.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(conf.Client(ctx)))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &Client{service}, err
}

type Client struct {
    service *androidpublisher.Service
}

func (c *Client) VerifyProduct(
    ctx context.Context,
    packageName string,
    productID string,
    token string,
) (*androidpublisher.ProductPurchase, error) {
    ps := androidpublisher.NewPurchasesProductsService(c.service)
    result, err := ps.Get(packageName, productID, token).Context(ctx).Do()

    return result, err
}

// test codes
  c, err := NewClientTrace([]byte(privateKey)) 
  if err != nil {
    return
  }

  packageName := "package.name"
  productID := "product_id"
  token := "xxxxx"
  r, err := c.VerifyProduct(context.Background(), packageName, productID, token)
```

However, it is failed to trace `http.Client`, There is no output of `GotConn`. Could someone help us to figure out the issue of the above codes?

Comment: What does "it is failed to trace" mean? `GotConn()` never gets called? How are you using the `Client` returned by `NewClientTrace()`?

Comment: @icza, there is no output of `GotConn()`. Also some test codes were updated to question

Comment: `fmt.Printf()` logs to standard output. Are you sure that is directed to where you expect it? `log.Printf()` logs to standard error, try that too.

Comment: @icza, the client code is done in test code `func TestClientTrace(t *testing.T)`.  the `fmt.Printf()` could be output in console

Comment: Can you show what `Client` is? And what's inside `c.VerifyProduct()`?

Comment: @icza, Sorry for missing those codes of Client, question has been updated

Comment: You want to trace requests from  oauth   or  androidpublisher?

Comment: @emptyhua, yes, we want to trace both the oauth and androidpublisher, and count the call number of google API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Requests from `google/oauth2` are not traceable by `httptrace`. your `ClientWrapper` passed with `context.WithValue` will be ignored [here](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/6b3c2da341f1ae337c2ca717bfb1cfef01aeed9b/internal/transport.go#L25), and oauth2 has [it's own http.Client](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/oauth2.go#L346), it just use the `Transport` method of `*http.Client` from context.Value.
2. Requests from androidpublisher can be traced by httptrace like this:

```golang
ctx := httptrace.WithClientTrace(context.Background(), clientWrapperTrace)
r, err := c.VerifyProduct(ctx, packageName, productID, token)
```

3. If you just want to count the requests, i think overwrite the `http.Client.Transport` is a easy way.

```golang
type TraceTransport struct {
}

func (t *TraceTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    fmt.Printf("RoundTrip hook %v\n", req.URL)
    return http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
}

func NewClientTrace(jsonKey []byte) (*Client, error) {
    cli := &http.Client{Transport: &TraceTransport{}}
    ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), oauth2.HTTPClient, cli)

    // ...
    service, err := androidpublisher.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(conf.Client(ctx)))
    // ....
}
```